# Сделать скролл для списка

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3

Есть обычный список ul, хочу научиться делать скролл у списка, допустим, чтоб из 10 цифр, отображалось только 4, а остальные только если пролистать вниз будут отображаться. Читал, про `overflow: scroll` - но, как-то задавал и получается чушь. Подскажите как сделать или где прочитать про способы скролла, буду благодарен.

```css
.for-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

li {}

a {}
```

```html
<ul class="for-ul">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вариант на чистом CSS (**фиксированная высота элементов списка**):

```css
.for-ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      border: 1px solid red;
      max-height: 120px;
      overflow-y: scroll
    }

    li {
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
    }

    a {}
```

```html
<ul class="for-ul">
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
    </ul>
```

2. Вариант на JavaScript (**динамическая высота элементов списка**):

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('.for-ul');
var li = ul.querySelectorAll('li');
var height = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  height = height + li[i].offsetHeight;
  console.log(height);
}
ul.style.maxHeight = height+'px';
```

```css
.for-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

a {}
```

```html
<ul class="for-ul">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3 Я немного длинне других пунктов списка</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
</ul>
```

3. Вариант на jQuery (**динамическая высота элементов списка**):

```js
var height = 0;
$('.for-ul li').each(function() {
  if ($(this).index() < 4) {
    height = height + $(this).outerHeight();
    console.log(height);
  }
});
$('.for-ul').css('max-height', height + 'px');
```

```css
.for-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

a {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="for-ul">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3 Я немного длинне других пунктов списка</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
</ul>
```